# How to save a webpage at its current state with images on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have scrolled down a lot on Facebook and now I want to save the page with the loaded content, including images, so I don't have to scroll and wait for it to load next time.

What I tried: copying the inner HTML of the body does not include images as it only contains the HTML code.

Comment: I think this question is offtopic hero on [so], because it doesn't involve any programming issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy the html of a page then save it as an html file & view it, the images might not work in case they're a relative path; meaning they should be manually & placed alongside your html, but I'm not sure if it's the case of Facebook.

Anyway, here's how to save a Webpage with chrome in general:

- You can save it as webpage with **Chrome Save As** by pressing Ctrl + S on keyboard on windows. And choose 1 of 3 options for saving as a Webpage: **HTML Only, Single File, Complete**. Below is a screenshot.
- You can press **Ctrl + P**, to save the page as a **PDF** file.
- You can install a **Chrome Extension**, to save the whole page as an Image. 1 extension is called GoFullPage.

[image]